# Решение проблемы с BB кодами

Tags: php, bbcode

Столкнулся с проблемой в BB кодах. Допустим есть тег [b][/b], выглядит это так:

```
$bbcode['/[b](.+)[/b]/isU'] = '<b>$1</b>';
```

Работает нормально. Но лишь стоит обрезать текст, например, до 10 символов, и если закрывающий тег не входит в этот список, начинается жуть.  Весь текст что идёт ниже (до самого низа сайта) - становится жирным, т.к. открывающий тег есть, а закрывающего нету.

Какое есть решение данной проблемы?

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: Если текст обрезан, и нет закрывающего тега, то в чём проблема что он становится жирным до самого конца?